# reallocate resources to a reduced task HPC 2012

Tags: allocation, hpc

I have 2 jobs, submitted under 2 templates in order to use priority levels.

I'm using Queued Scheduling, with Graceful Pre-emption and all the automatic resource adjustment enabled.

I submit the low priority job. At a later stage I allocate the higher priority job. HPC 2012 automatically takes resources from the lower priority task as the running tasks within the job complete.

HPC then does NOT reallocate those resources back the lower priority task when the higher priority one completes.

This gets even worse as the application submitting the tasks/jobs adds further tasks to running jobs as certain tasks complete, and I typically have only a handful of cores allocated to the low priority one, despite there being several hundred cores free once the high priority job completes.

Is there a way to change HPC configuration to do this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the HPC Pack 2012 SP1 notes state that this exact issue has been fixed in SP1 for SOA mode. To clarify, it HAS also been fixed for Batch mode.

This is how it works (when using Batch mode, queued scheduling with graceful pre-emption)
Submit a low priority job
Scheduler allocates resources to the tasks under the low job.
Submit a high job
As tasks under the low priority job complete the resources are allocated to the tasks under the high priority.

Under HPC Pack 2012, the resources on the low job can be run right down to a single core and the job would carry on trying to finish with a single core allocated (unless you also put in conditions on minimum numbers allocated).

Under HPC Pack 2012 SP1, it will allocate resources to the high job more aggressively (it will take ALL the resources from the low job as the already-running tasks finish) and label the tasks as cancelled in the Activity Log.

As the resources free up as the high priority job's tasks complete these are re-allocated to the low priority job, which now just appears as a queued task, so normal task-level prioritisation/scheduling occurs, exactly as if this low task had been submitted separately. It therefore gets full resources re-allocated.